# nHibernate: Unable to locate persister

Tags: nhibernate

Running VS2003, nHB 3.0.0.3001, trying to run a unit test through Gallio 3.2. The code is from the first session of "Summer of nHibernate". I am getting the following error when attempting to run the test.

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate persister: DataTransfer.Customer
TargetSite: Void OnLoad(NHibernate.Event.LoadEvent, NHibernate.Event.LoadType)
HelpLink: null
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(String entityName, Object id)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Type entityClass, Object id)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get[T](Object id)
at DataAccessLayer.NhibernateDataProvider.GetCustomerById(Int32 customerId)
```

My very uneducated guess is that the Customer class cannot be seen. But both the unit test and the data access layers have a reference to the DataTransfer assembly that holds the Customer class. The Customer class is public and all the properties are public virtual.

The nHB config file is in the directory, and the Customer mapping file is an embedded resource. Seems to fail on the 
line:

```
return session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Make sure your mapping file is named *.hbm.xml
2. Make sure it is set to an embedded resource.
3. If these fail, debug and when it fails, catch the exception and look at the InnerException - NHibernate has fantastic error messaging hidden in there.

Hope those thigs help out - otherwise we can look into some other options (but 1 and 2 solve 90% of persister problems)

Comment: FYI - for item 2, look at the XML file properties in studio, it's the top combo box (I believe the default is Don't Copy but I do not have Studio open).

Comment: Yes, mapping file was named hbn.xml not hbm.xml thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd also add a 2.5 to your list make sure you are loading the mapping assembly when creating your factory.

Comment: In my case the build action was "Embedded Resource" but I was still getting the same error. 
These steps solved it for me:
1) Change build action something other than "Embedded Resource"
2) Save
3) Change it back to "Embedded Resource"
4) Save

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ActiveRecord for entity mapping, got the same error when tried to use ISession.Get, 
instead of using configuration for retrieving session, like this:

```
                     ISession session = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()
                    .Configure()
                    .AddAssembly(typeof(Account).Assembly)
                    .SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor())
                    .BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
```

I changed it to work through ActiveRecordMediator:

```
                    ISession session = Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordMediator
                    .GetSessionFactoryHolder().
                    CreateSession(typeof(Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase));
```

now its working great..

Answer (score 0):

On your hibernate.cfg.xml file, add this code:

```
 <mapping assembly="(name of your Assembly Project)" />
```

Basically, on your code its:

```
 <mapping assembly="DataTransfer" />
```